# Java JFrame remove and repaint components not working

Tags: java, jframe

So I started to go into OOP and also started to learn about swing library but I have trouble. When I try to remove all of the JFrame components it doesnt work. What I want to do is when the user clicks a button I have to remove all the JFrame components and add new ones but it doesn't work despite that I used removeAll() repait(), revalidate() etc. Here is my code for the BankApp class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BankApp{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BankGUI object1;
    object1 = new BankGUI();
    object1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    object1.setSize(700, 500);
    object1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    object1.setResizable(false);
    object1.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Here is the BankGUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BankGUI extends JFrame{

private JButton CreateAccount;
private JButton LoginAccount;
private JButton Exit;
private JButton AboutButton;
private JButton ExitButton;
private JLabel IntroText;


public BankGUI(){
    super("Banking App");
    createMainMenu();

}

public void createMainMenu(){
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,40)));
    IntroText = new JLabel("Banking Application");
    IntroText.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(280,60));
    IntroText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 34));
    IntroText.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    add(IntroText);

    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,40)));

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    CreateAccount = new JButton("Register");
    CreateAccount.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,50));
    CreateAccount.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    CreateAccount.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    CreateAccount.setFocusable(false);
    add(CreateAccount);

    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));

    LoginAccount = new JButton("Login");
    LoginAccount.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,50));
    LoginAccount.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    LoginAccount.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    LoginAccount.setFocusable(false);
    add(LoginAccount);

    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));

    AboutButton = new JButton("About");
    AboutButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,50));
    AboutButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    AboutButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    AboutButton.setFocusable(false);
    add(AboutButton);

    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));

    ExitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    ExitButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,50));
    ExitButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    ExitButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    ExitButton.setFocusable(false);
    add(ExitButton);

    ButtonListener actionListener = new ButtonListener(CreateAccount, LoginAccount, AboutButton, ExitButton);
    CreateAccount.addActionListener(actionListener);
    LoginAccount.addActionListener(actionListener);
    AboutButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    ExitButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
}
```

And here is my ButtonListener Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
private JButton CreateAccount;
private JButton LoginAccount;
private JButton AboutButton;
private JButton ExitButton;


public ButtonListener(JButton button1,JButton button2,JButton button3,JButton button4){
    CreateAccount = button1;
    LoginAccount = button2;
    AboutButton = button3;
    ExitButton = button4;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    BankGUI bankgui = new BankGUI();
    if(e.getSource() == CreateAccount){
        System.out.println("This prints out");
    }else if(e.getSource() == ExitButton){
        bankgui.getContentPane().removeAll();
        bankgui.removeAll();
        bankgui.validate();
        bankgui.repaint();
        System.out.println("Code reaches here but it doesnt clear the screen");
    }
}


}
```

When I try to do it nothing happens despite that I revalidate and repaint I'm not sure why.I just want to clear the JFrame. I'm 100% sure that the code reaches the methods but for some reason they don't work.
Maybe its obvious mistake but I'm not seeing it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `bankgui.removeAll();` is a bad idea, as it will remove the content pane and possibly the root pane.  The methods you are looking for are `revalidate` and `repaint`.  Having said that, [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) would be a far superior solution.  It might require you to change you way of thinking as  `ButtonListener` may not be the appropriate class to be making decisions about overall navigation

Comment: I will take a look at CardLayout thanks for the suggestion. Since I'm starting I don't have a clue to which layout is the best in this situation. About revalidate and repaint I tried it and it still doesn't work I mean the screen stays the same even thought I used all these methods. I'm not sure where the problem comes from.

Comment: In your `actionPerformed` method, you are creating a new instance of `BankGUI`, this is not the same as the instance of that is presented to the user

Comment: Wow thanks for pointing it out I'm not sure how that happened. I guess I have to rewrite the structure of the program using CardLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method, you are creating *another* instance of `BankGUI`, this is, in no way, connected to the instance which is been displayed to the user...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    BankGUI bankgui = new BankGUI();
    //...
}
```

There are a few ways you "might" correct this, most of them aren't pretty.

You could pass a reference of `BankGUI` to the `ButtonListener` along with the buttons.  I don't like this idea, as it provides the means for `ButtonListener` to start doing things to `BankGUI` it really has no responsibility for doing.

You could use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`, passing a reference of the button which was triggered, to get a reference to the window.  This has the sam problem as the previous idea, but it also makes assumptions about the structure of the UI, which, `ButtonListener` shouldn't care about.

In both cases, this couples `ButtonListener` to `BankGUI`.

A better solution would be to provide some kind of "navigation manager".  The `ButtonListener` would take a reference of it and when one of the buttons is actioned, would notify the "navigation manager", asking it to perform the actual task.

This de-couples the `ButtonListener` from the implementation of the UI.

This is all about concepts of "isolation of responsibility", "code reusability" and "model-view-controller"

Overall, a simpler and more practical solution would be to use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which will further de-couple the UI and make it easier to isolate functionality to their own classes/components and allow the primary UI to switch between them

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import static java.awt.Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavaApplication101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BankGUI object1;
                object1 = new BankGUI();
                object1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                object1.pack();
                object1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                object1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface BankNavigationController {

        public void setView(String command);
    }

    public static class CardLayoutBankNavigationController implements BankNavigationController {

        private Container parent;
        private CardLayout layout;

        public CardLayoutBankNavigationController(Container parent, CardLayout layout) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void setView(String command) {
            layout.show(parent, command);
        }

    }

    public static class BankGUI extends JFrame {

        private CardLayoutBankNavigationController controller;

        public BankGUI() {
            super("Banking App");
            CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(layout);
            controller = new CardLayoutBankNavigationController(getContentPane(), layout);

            add("Main Menu", createMainMenu());
            add("Register", otherView("Register"));
            add("Login", otherView("Login"));
            add("About", otherView("About"));
            add("Exit", otherView("Exit"));

            controller.setView("Main Menu");
        }

        public JPanel otherView(String named) {
            JPanel view = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            view.add(new JLabel(named), gbc);

            JButton mainMenu = new JButton("Main Menu");
            view.add(mainMenu, gbc);

            ButtonListener actionListener = new ButtonListener(controller);
            mainMenu.addActionListener(actionListener);

            return view;
        }

        public JPanel createMainMenu() {
            JPanel menu = new JPanel();
            menu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menu, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            menu.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 40)));
            JLabel IntroText = new JLabel("Banking Application");
            IntroText.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            IntroText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 34));
            IntroText.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            menu.add(IntroText);

            menu.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 40)));

            JButton CreateAccount = new JButton("Register");
            CreateAccount.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            CreateAccount.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            CreateAccount.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            CreateAccount.setFocusable(false);
            menu.add(CreateAccount);

            menu.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));

            JButton LoginAccount = new JButton("Login");
            LoginAccount.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            LoginAccount.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            LoginAccount.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            LoginAccount.setFocusable(false);
            menu.add(LoginAccount);

            menu.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));

            JButton AboutButton = new JButton("About");
            AboutButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            AboutButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            AboutButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            AboutButton.setFocusable(false);
            menu.add(AboutButton);

            menu.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));

            JButton ExitButton = new JButton("Exit");
            ExitButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            ExitButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            ExitButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            ExitButton.setFocusable(false);
            menu.add(ExitButton);

            ButtonListener actionListener = new ButtonListener(controller);
            CreateAccount.addActionListener(actionListener);
            LoginAccount.addActionListener(actionListener);
            AboutButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
            ExitButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

            return menu;
        }
    }

    public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private BankNavigationController controller;

        public ButtonListener(BankNavigationController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.setView(e.getActionCommand());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided along with the code! I guess I will take that extra time to learn about CardLayout since it will help me in the future.